# React show information from one component to another that don't have common parant

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following react router:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={MyHeader}>
        <IndexRoute component={Main}/>
        <Route path="carwash" component={CarWashPage} />
        <Route path="carwashAdd" component={AddCarWashPage} />
        <Route path="carwashAdd/:carWashId" component={EditCarWashPage} />

    </Route>
</Router>,
destination
);
```

In component `AddCarWashPage` I have a form for carWash and when it is submitted I make redirection (`browtherHistory.push('/carwash')`) to component `CarWashPage`.

Now afte redirection I want to show in component `CarWashPage` information that carwash was save succesfully. How can I pass this text or maybe some flag from `AddCarWashPage` to `CarWashPage` that `CarWashPage` may to know when the correcsponding text has to be shown ?

Comment: I think you can pass params via push method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is Redux. If you're not looking to add this library, then you need to have either a global state bus (could get messy) or a common ancestor. Both of those routes are children to `MyHeader`. If you'd like to use the common ancestor approach then you could have `MyHeader` pass down a callback to the child.

Redux is still the way to go though so I highly recommend it.